# Left outer Join query returns duplicates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, duplicates, left-join

I have a table 1 (`MID, SSN, ...`) `MID` is primary key and table 2 (`ID, SSN, StateCode..`) where `ID` and `SSN` make up the primary key. I'm trying to display all columns from  table 1 along with `StateCode` from table 2 matching it against `SSN`. Tbl 1 has 50 rows and some have same `SSN` values.

If no `SSN` match is found from table 2, displaying a NULL in `StateCode` is acceptable, so I chose left join. Here is my query

```
Select 
    tbl1.*, tbl2.StateCode
from 
    tbl1
left outer join 
    tbl2 on tbl1.SSN = tbl2.SSN
```

I'm looking to retrieve 50 records, but I get 70, rows that contain the same ssn value in tbl1 ends up duplicated in the final output. What is going wrong?

Comment: SSN must be unique in each table for your join to return non-duplicates

Comment: @pixelbits If join isn't the way to do this, what do you suggest for another option?

Comment: What do you want returned in your select list? Your select list will determine how the query is constructed. It will involve a couple of sub-selects and then a join - ugly, but it'll work.

Comment: I'm trying to return all columns in table 1, and Statecode from table 2, displaying either NULL or a value. SSN is the common column in both these tables, in table 1 there are duplicate ssn.

Comment: Try this: select distinct SSN from  tbl1, then try select * from tbl1. Do they return the same  number of rows? I'm trying to find out if SSN is unique in tbl1

Comment: They do not return same no of rows. SSN in table 1 is not unique, in table 2 it is unique

Comment: If SSN is not unique in table 1 and you're returning all columns in table1, then you can't expect SSN to be unique. Doing select * from tbl1 will return duplicate SSNs, and that's not joining to anything. You need to narrow down your select columns in tbl1

Comment: table 1 has 50 rows and SSN is a regular column that can contain the same value in more than one row. I'm trying to retrieve StateCode column table 2 which has distinct SSN. Using left join i expected 50 rows to be returned but it is returning 70

Comment: If table1 has 50 rows and the left join with table2 returns 70, then some of the table1 rows *must* have matched with 2 or more rows from table2 *each*. For it is the join that has produced the duplicates. And looking at the join condition, I can only conclude that you are mistaken about SSN being unique in table2. But surely it should be easy to verify with something like `SELECT COUNT(SSN), COUNT(DISTINCT SSN) FROM table2`.

Comment: thanks @Andriy, you were right, after i ran this query it is not unique the ssn in table 2, and ended up getting all the matching rows!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest reading on [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

If you have 50 rows in the first table and 70 in the second that makes 3500 rows.  The join condition `tbl1.SSN = tbl2.SSN` will filter out rows but you may well end up with more than 50 rows.

Back to your problem you can see what is happening by trying the following :

```
SELECT 
  tbl1.*,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl1.SSN = tbl2.SSN) AS NbResultTbl2
FROM 
  tbl1
```

This will tell which rows of `tbl1` has multiple match in `tbl2`.  If you have a number higher than 1 in the `NbResultTbl2` column then you are going to end up with duplicates.

To eliminate those duplicates you can try this :

```
SELECT 
  tbl1.*,
  (SELECT TOP 1 StateCode FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl1.SSN = tbl2.SSN) 
FROM 
  tbl1
```

This will get the first `StateCode` found for a matching SNN in tbl2.

Comment: i tried reading through although i couldn't infer why a left join would retrieve more rows than what exists in tbl1, since ssn in table 2 is distinct

Comment: See updated answer to check if `ssn` in table is really distinct.

Comment: Thank you, it was not distinct, I came up with another query but yours is short and clean! Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try using SELECT DISTINCT rather than just SELECT statement, SELECT DISTINCT won't show duplicates

Comment: i want all the columns from table 1 along with statecode from table 2, when i do distinct i'm losing data, fewer than 50 rows are being returne

Comment: I'm a little confused from your original question where you say displaying a null is acceptable. have you tried adding a Where condition such as WHERE ColumnName IS NOT NULL

Comment: NULL is acceptable as a value in StateCode if an ssn from table 1 is not found in table 2. I'm trying to show all 50 rows along with StateCode that match the SSN for that row

Comment: Also if you are looking to retrieve 50 records, do your tables each have more than 50 records or does one have exactly 50 records? If you have exactly 50 in one table then it should be simple just figure out the correct joining

Comment: Yes table 1 has exactly 50 rows, and table 2 contains distinct SSN and the Statecode value. I'm not sure why my left join is retrieving duplicates and final result more than what is present in table 1

Answer (score 0):

To add to the comment by pixelbits. You can perform a subquery with (skip MID)

```
 select distinct ssn,* from tbl1
```

And left join that to tbl2

That should give your 50 rows unless other columns besides MID are distinct

Comment: When i do distinct im actually losing data its returning fewer rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

"ID and SSN are both primary keys" . . . This statement indicates a lack of understanding of what a primary key is.  A table can have only one primary key.  A primary key *can* be composite (composed of more than one column), but there is only one.

If `MID` is the primary key for table1, then presumably multiple rows can have the same SSN.

Your query is:

```
Select *
from tbl1, tbl2.StateCode
from tbl1, tbl2 left outer join tbl2 on tbl1.SSN = tbl2.SSN
```

This is not even valid SQL.  You might try this version:

```
Select distinct tbl1.*, tbl2.StateCode
from tbl1 left outer join
     tbl2
     on tbl1.SSN = tbl2.SSN;
```

This is valid and would appear to be what you want.

Comment: I tried this, and I still get 70 rows on doing the left outer join in this way, all the rows with same ssn gets duplicated more. I'm not sure why this is

Comment: @sandr . . . Maybe `select distinct` will remove the rows that you think are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping SSN within Table2 and getting the MAX StateCode:

```
SELECT Table1.*, DT.StateCode
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT SSN, MAX(StateCode) AS StateCode FROM Table2 GROUP BY SSN
) DT ON Table1.SSN = DT.SSN
```

Comment: query didn't work, grouping wasn't possible as the other columns didn't comply under this condition, i'm trying to select all of table 1 and one column from table 2

Comment: Okay, try a nested select that returns only one state code for each SSN

Answer (score 0):

Try,
Your both Table have one more primary key is there So just try ID column to match

```
Select tbl1.MID,tbl1.SSN, tbl2.StateCode
from tbl1
left outer join tbl2 
on tbl1.MID= tbl2.ID
Group by tbl1.MID,tbl1.SSN, tbl2.StateCode
```